# Não estou conseguindo configurar os drivers do sqlsrv no php7

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, driver

No arquivo `php.ini` todas as extensões são encontradas, menos as que eu preciso para conectar ao banco de dados SQL Server.

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
```

As `.dll` estão na pasta `C:\php7\ext.`

No `php.ini` está mapeado:

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
extension_dir = "C:\php7\ext"
```

Quando executo o `php.exe`, ele retorna a seguinte mensagem:

> `the procedure entry point call_user_function could not be locale in the dynamic library C:\php7\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll`
>   `the procedure entry point call_user_function could not be locale in the dynamic library C:\php7\ext\php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll`

Comment: Você instalou o apache e php seperados? quais foram as versões? e para qual plataforma (x86 ou x64)

Comment: @rray poderia adicionar estes detalhes (x86, x64) em sua resposta para oficializar a dup

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento posso sim, acho o problema dessa pergunta é outro ... geralmente quando vc instala algum programa x64 (no windows) sempre precisa baixar manualmente algum complemento (ex c++ 20xx redistributable ou afim).

Answer (score 3):

Baixe o pacote [Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) e descompacte em uma pasta e pegue esses dois arquivos para a pasta `ext` do [php](/questions/tagged/php):

> Para `x86`:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86.dll
```

> Para `x64`:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
```

---

*Teste a conexão com:*

```
$localhost = "localhost";
$database  = "testdb";
$user = "sa";
$pass = "12345";
$c = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$localhot;Database=$database", $user,$pass);
```

adequando as configurações a do seu banco.

<sub>**Referencias:**</sub>

- [Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098)
- [PDO_SQLSRV DSN](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php)
- [Documentation - Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd903047(SQL.11).aspx)

Comment: +1 Mas eu gostaria que você desenvolvesse mais a resposta, por favor. Por exemplo, como configurar a pasta pro Windows no php.ini e como incluir as extensões nesse arquivo.

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway, então você pode abrir como pergunta, porque, a instalação do PHP vai depender do servidor que utiliza, no meu caso para desenvolvimento utilizo IIS ele já instala para mim e coloca numa pasta `C:\Arquivos de Programas\PHP`, mas, antigamente fazia muita instalação no `APACHE` que dava muito trabalho mas, era compensador. Se eu colocar isso na resposta vai mudar muito o enfoque, por favor, se pode abrir uma questão relacionando dessa pergunta, com enfoque na instalação, explicando sua realidade ? Geralmente é baixar o pacote e instalar para o determinado Servidor.

Comment: **continuando:** a instalação de `ext` é bem simples dentro da pasta [tag:php] tem a pata `ext` coloque a .dll (no caso do windows) e reinicie o servidor, e muito simples.

Answer (score 2):

Eu também tive problema e não consegui dessa forma, eu usei no PDO mesmo e deu certo

```
  $p= new PDO('odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=NOMEDOSERVER;Database=NOMEDOBANCO; Uid=LOGIN;Pwd=SENHA');

  $stmt = $p->prepare("SELECT *  FROM usuario");
```