# PHP PDO para SQL SERVER

Tags: php, pdo, driver

Boa tarde,

Estou tentando conectar com minhas páginas PHP no MS SQL SERVER usando PDO, porém estou com dificuldades. Tentei usar o manual do PHP, mas estou ficando confuso e não estou conseguindo. A página está retornando esse erro: Failed to get DB handle: could not find driver. tentei baixar os drivers do site da microsoft, mas não funcionou também. Olhei aqui no forum e nada tbm, olhei nesses posts:
[Drivers PDO para SQL Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48078/drivers-pdo-para-sql-server)
[Como conectar PHP 5.6 ao Sql Server 2008?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88551/como-conectar-php-5-6-ao-sql-server-2008/153030#153030)
[Erro ao tentar conectar bd MSSQL Server usando PDO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175048/erro-ao-tentar-conectar-bd-mssql-server-usando-pdo)

OBS.: Estou usando windows 10; 
PHP versão 5.6.25;
SQL SERVER 2014 EXPRESS;

Obrigado!

Comment: Consegui conectar usando pdo_odbc, mas senti que a conexão está um pouco lenta.

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175222/n%C3%A3o-estou-conseguindo-configurar-os-drivers-do-sqlsrv-no-php7/175226#175226

Comment: Pelo que entendi, o problema nesse caso é que o Windows 10 precisa pelo menos da versão 4.0 do driver e o PHP 5.6 exige a versão 3.2 do driver.
Mais informações aqui:
https://www.dirceuresende.com/blog/como-conectar-no-sql-server-utilizando-o-php-xampp-e-o-driver-pdo-no-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Será necessário alguns arquivos .dll que você poderá encontrar no seguinte link:
 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098
Como seu PHP é o 5.6, Baixe o Arquivo SQLSRV32.

Após baixar o arquivo, você irá extrai-lo, lá você terá as dlls necessárias.

utilize o phpinfo(), para verificar qual o PHP Extension Build. [image: PHP Extension Build].
no caso do exemplo você terá que copiar as dlls que tenham _ts.dll do php 5.6, ou seja:
php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll e php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll,
Copie estes arquivos para os respectivos diretórios,
C:/.../php/ext e também para o C:/windows/system32/ e/ou para o C:/windows/SysWOW64 caso sejá computador de 64bits.

Feito isso você deverá abrir o php.ini e na sessão de extension você deverá acrescentar as seguintes linhas:

extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

e remover o ";" da linha extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll, caso ainda esteja comentada.

[image: php.ini]
Será necessário também a instalação Microsoft® ODBC Driver para SQL Server[Native Client] que irá depender de seu banco de dados no caso como exemplo passarei o link do Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 para SQL Server.

https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=36434

Após a instalação completa dos passos anteriores. você deverá restartar o apache.

se tudo estiver correto você poderá acessar novamente o phpinfo() e poderá pesquisar por sqlsrv [image: sqlsrv]

e em seguida por pdo_sqlsrv [image: pdo_sqlsrv]
<sub>(fonte: [synet.sk](http://www.synet.sk/images/cms/pdo_sqlsrv_phpinfo.png))</sub>
espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Desculpe a demora em responder, eu fiz exatamente os passos citados acima, tentei praticamente com todas as dll's que encontrei e mesmo assim não funcionou.